# Pass an array of values as seperate function arguments in Powershell

Tags: powershell, pinvoke

I'm trying to write some Powershell to make in-memory calls to the Win32API. For this I need to pass the Win32API function prototype as well as the actual arguments. To make the code more neat I figured I'll only pass the arguments as an array and extract the types from there to create the prototype. For this to work I need to be able to 'explode' an array into separate function arguments. I'm new to Powershell so I've no idea if this is possible. If it is the question is: **How can you 'explode' an array into seperate function arguments?**

Below I've added the relevant part of the code.

```
function CallWin32API(
    [String] $ModuleName,
    [String]$FunctionName,
    [array]$Arguments,
    [Type]$ReturnType=[Void]
) {
    $Prototype = @()
    foreach ($Argument in $Arguments) {
        $Prototype += $Argument.GetType()
    }

    # ...
    # Using the $Prototype here somewhere & creating the delegate
    # ...

    $Delegate = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer($FunctionAddr, $DelegateType)

    # This is what I need but does not work
    $Delegate.Invoke($Arguments)

    # This is not what I need but does work
    $Delegate.Invoke([IntPtr]::Zero,"Hello World","This is My MessageBox",0)
}
CallWin32API user32.dll MessageBoxA @([IntPtr]::Zero,"Hello World","This is My MessageBox",0) ([int])
```

EDIT: I'm trying to dynamically call Win32API functions. This means that the arguments of the `$Delegate.Invoke` depend on the function that is being called.

Comment: What is the signature of `.SomeFunction` ? You might be able to just `.SomeFunction.Invoke($Arguments)`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I've updated the question based on your remark. The signature of the function I'm trying to call with the array is based on the array itself as I'm calling the function using reflection.

Comment: You can pass a single array and have the runtime explode it for you by using another level of indirection: `$Delegate.Invoke.Invoke($Arguments)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That did indeed do the trick! It works now!

Comment: As aside, sounds like [`Ctypes` Module](https://github.com/jborean93/PowerShell-ctypes/tree/d174ddf26881a0c49831ba7041a67915e6abacdd) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without having complete information but using [`MessageBoxA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxa) as example you can always use [`.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmethod.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0#system-management-automation-psmethod-invoke(system-object())) from [`PSMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmethod?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0) to bind the array of arguments:

```bash
Add-Type '
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Testing
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int MessageBoxA(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        string lpText,
        string lpCaption,
        uint uType);
}'

function CallWin32API {
    param(
        [array] $Arguments
    )

    [Testing]::MessageBoxA.Invoke($Arguments)
}

CallWin32API @([IntPtr]::Zero, 'Hello World', 'This is My MessageBox', 0)
```

---

Following comment from [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154906/pass-an-array-of-values-as-seperate-function-arguments-in-powershell/78155111#comment137784648_78154906), if you have the delegate from [`GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer?view=net-8.0) you can also call `PSMethod.Invoke` on `Delegate.Invoke`:

```bash
using namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices
using namespace System.Linq.Expressions
using namespace System.Reflection

$lib = [NativeLibrary]::Load('user32')
$functionPtr = [NativeLibrary]::GetExport($lib, 'MessageBoxA')
$customDelegate = [Delegate]::CreateDelegate(
    [Func[Type[], Type]],
    [Expression].Assembly.GetType('System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.DelegateHelpers').
        GetMethod('MakeNewCustomDelegate', [BindingFlags] 'NonPublic, Static'))

$customDelegateType = [IntPtr], [string], [string], [uint], [int]
$delegate = [Marshal]::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
    $functionPtr,
    $customDelegate.Invoke($customDelegateType))

$arguments = [IntPtr]::Zero, 'Hello World', 'This is My MessageBox', 0
$delegate.Invoke.Invoke($arguments)
```